# Is it possible to make jackson 2 recognize @codehause...JsonIgnoreProperties?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using `Jackson 2`, but need use one library which uses `Jackson 1`(codehause), and makes call to its remote server.

But  because the client-server version mismatches, the server side returns fields that are not recognized by client mode class.
So it failed with error like:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field

The client model class is actually annotated with `@codehause...JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

So I am wondering is there a way to make `Jackson 2` recognizes `Jackson 1` `@codehause`...`JsonIgnoreProperties`, and just ignore unknown properties?

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In `Jackson 2`, You can configure the `ObjectMapper` to ignore unknown fields as follows:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Amila, The problem is that we are using a client library, which wraps all these stuff: it uses httpClient to send request, and deserialize the json data to its object. - but it uses jackson 1 @JsonIgnoreProperties. We can't change the code.  I tried ContextResolver<ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>> approach, but the client code is not aware of the customized ObjectMapper at all - instead creates a new default ObjectMapper